# Дизайн формы html,css

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, есть код:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF - 8">
    <title>Форма</title>
    <script src="window.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1 align = "center">Создание таблици</h1>
 <form action = "">
  <fieldset>
  <label>Введите число: </label>
  <input type = "text" id = "txtName" />
  <input type="button" value="Построение таблици" onClick="">
  </fieldset>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Хотелось бы чтобы форма распологалась по центру страници (при этом поле для ввода бло над кнопкой), имела определенный размер, а ее рамка имела заокругленные края. Как это сделать? Если Вы считаете. что код некорректен  под корректируйте, пожалуйста и укажите на недостаток.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
form {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
fieldset {
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
}
fieldset input[type=button] {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Форма</title>
  <script src="window.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Создание таблици</h1>
  <form action="POST">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="txtName">Введите число:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtName">
      <input type="button" value="Построение таблици">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: спасибо, а добавив background: ..... к форме можно задать ее цвет?

Comment: и что делает атрибут post в form?

Comment: Можно, background задает фон любого элемента. Post это метод передачи данных из формы, надо хоть что-то указывать POST или GET

Comment: еще раз спасибо

Comment: а чтобы форма была по центру страници (вертикально), это valign:middle?